# How to force email address to be a unique identifier?

Tags: wordpress, civimember

We're using Civi 4.7 in WordPress, making make use of organisations and individuals and new individuals get a WordPress login (synced).

It comes unstuck periodically when an administration uses a person's email (someone@domain.com) for an organisation contact, but then tries to use the same email address as their personal (employee) record.

The first time the record is created a WP user is created and attached, having the matching email address. When the individual record is subsequently setup there's nothing preventing (or warning) the admin NOT to use the same email, but a new WP account is not created or linked because WP will not allow two users with the same email address.

What usually then happens is that the admin will remove the offending email address from the organisation record and pop it into the individual record, expecting everything to link up. Naturally it doesn't so the next step is someone then tries to fix it by deleting the WP user and/or the organisation record. Chaos ensues.

Can I prevent an admin or member from entering an email address into a contact when that email is already in use elsewhere?

If an email is moved between records as described above, is it possible to re-link the wordpress user to the new record? I couldn't find any way to do this short of hacking away at the database.

All advice welcome!

Comment: This was partially answered here:
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22969/wordpress-user-record-url-doesnt-show-for-one-user-cant-see-why

(as far as what happens and how to fix it by hacking the database). I'd love to know if there's a way to prevent it or at least fix it via the UI. It happens rather frequently.