# WordPress - user record URL doesn't show for one user. Can't see why?

Tags: wordpress, civimember, contacts, profile

In the user detail view for a member with a WordPress account there's usually a link to the WordPress user record like so:

Contact ID / User ID   :   1354  / **1561**

For one member the user ID doesn't appear and I'm stumped.

- I've deleted and recreated both the Civi and WP records several times.
- dumping the WP user record and toggling membership off/on does recreate the WP record (but doesn't show the link to it)
- We use the profile sync plugin and this is working fine (i.e. name changes sync to wordpress profile and vice versa)

Digging through the template code shows the {$userRecordUrl} variable as the trigger for showing it or not, so I assume this isn't set somehow.

Has anyone seen this behaviour?

The user for whom it *does* work was created some time ago -- perhaps its functionality that is no longer present in 4.7? I can't find any documentation to support that though.

thanks!
- Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this happen when there are multiple WordPress accounts using the same email address.

These values are stored in the `civicrm_uf_match` table of the database.  If my first suggestion doesn't pan out, you may want to browse that table and look for duplicate values for `contact_id` and `uf_id` (the "WordPress user id") corresponding to this user.  Delete the offending record(s) in this table and let CiviCRM recreate them.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful. It was the civicrm_uf_match table as you suggested. Correcting the record to point at the right Civi and WP identifiers fixed the issue.

Is there some way to do this from within the UI (i.e. without manually editing the database?)

Comment: @ChrisCarey There's a "middle option" between manually editing the database and the UI, which is the API Explorer.  I detail this technique for a very similar issue here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/18876/12